# About geometry_msgs/Twist

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any instructions about the meaning of geometry_msgs/Twist elements? e.g. What's the unit of linear and angular, m/s? degree/min? degree/s?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12149/about-geometry_msgs/twist/) by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
These are just msgs in a structured way so that they can be published or subscribed by a node. They are just values. It depends on the node which actually uses them to manipulate robot.
It depends on how you want to use it. For example in teleop_base package the teleop_base_keyboard.cpp takes the msgs from keyboard and uses them as m/sec. If your node takes this msgs as mm/sec then the node execution will be accordingly.

You can know the msg types by the following command.

```
rosmsg show geometry_msgs/Twist
```

whose output is

```
geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
```

Hope this helps, Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on 2011-11-29**:
Thanks, I'll read sources of p2os package.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that the units are defined in REP103 on "Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions" here:
http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on 2011-11-30**:
It helps, thanks.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-09**:
Is there a preferred way to initialise such a variable?
Let s say I declar ein my program:

```
geometry_msgs/Twist datas
```

can I initialise the vector as:

```
datas = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

???
I thought it was like e structure's initialisation but it doesn t compile